# Accessing Long Multidimensional Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access the following array,

```
Array
(
    [return] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [issue] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [first] => activeissue.socustomername
                                    [second] => TEST123
                                    [key] => activeissue.socustomername
                                    [value] => TEST123
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [first] => activeissue.customername
                                    [second] => TEST123
                                    [key] => activeissue.customername
                                    [value] => TEST123
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [first] => activeissue.customerid
                                    [second] => 1131
                                    [key] => activeissue.customerid
                                    [value] => 1131
                                )



                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [issue] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [first] => activeissue.socustomername
                                    [second] => TEST4321
                                    [key] => activeissue.socustomername
                                    [value] => TEST4321
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [first] => activeissue.customername
                                    [second] => Aspire Trust
                                    [key] => activeissue.customername
                                    [value] => Aspire Trust
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [first] => activeissue.customerid
                                    [second] => 1132321
                                    [key] => activeissue.customerid
                                    [value] => 1132321
                                )

                        )
                )

        )
)
```

I can't get my head round to loop through and return each issue,

I can manually get the data, but I really need to loop through each individual issue,

I have tried to double Foreach it, but i'm sure there is a much easier way that works, unlike myn,

```
foreach($array as $key['issue'] => $value){

foreach($value[0]['issue'] as $subkey){

echo $subkey['key'].' : '.$subkey['value'];

                                      }

}
```

I only get returned one issue, I know its because i am only accessing [0] but I don't know how to loop through again to access the next set of data,

Any help would be great, welcome any advice too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($array['return'] as $group) {

      foreach ($group['issue'] as $issue) {
           echo $issue['key'].' : '.$issue['value'];
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will test soon.

Comment: Works, Cheers :)